# And condition in Yii with condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How can i use AND in Mysql in Yii.

I tried.Here is my condition

```
$cid =$list['cid'];
$sid =$list['sid'];
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$con = 'cid=:cid';
$arr = array(':cid'=>$cid,);
if($sid!=null){
 $con = $con.'AND sid=:sid'; 
 array_push($arr, ':sid'=>$sid);  //here i have error
 }
$criteria->condition = $con;
$criteria->params = $arr;
$result = Product::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Sometimes only I have sid. I can't push condition in to array. So how can I do it in yii?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not "array_push", try this:

```
$arr[':sid'] = $sid;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be so designed

```
$cid =$list['cid'];
$sid =$list['sid'];
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = 'cid=:cid';
$criteria->params = array(':cid'=>$cid,);
if($sid!=null){
    $criteria->addCondition('sid=:sid');
    $criteria->params[':sid'] = $sid; // or $criteria->params = array_merge($criteria->params, array(':sid'=>$sid));
}
$result = Product::model()->findAll($criteria);
```